# How to create polygon from bbox data in python?

Tags: python, r, polygon, geopandas, point

I have created a code in R which extracts `bbox` from a list of points and then creates a polygon using `st_as_sfc`. Now I am trying to do the same in python where I was able to get the `bbox` coordinates from the list of points data and then tried to create polygon using the two points by help of `shapely.geometry` which is throwing error. Is there any alternative for `st_as_sfc` in python or how can I create a polygon from the obtained `bbox` coordinates?

R code:-

```
print(st_as_sfc(st_bbox(sgrid)))
result:-
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -9574057 ymin: 3590448 xmax: -9494057 ymax: 3670448
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
POLYGON ((-9574057 3590448, -9494057 3590448, -...
```

Python :-
data frame from bbox coordinates xmin,ymin and xmax,ymax

```
from shapely import geometry
print(df)
              x             y                               geometry
0  3.418932e+06 -2.088506e+07  POINT (-20885056.99629 3418931.63321)
1  3.478932e+06 -2.082506e+07  POINT (-20825056.99629 3478931.63321)
poly = geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in gdf_p['geometry'].tolist()])
print(poly.wkt)
```

error:-

```
ValueError: A linearring requires at least 4 coordinates.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a dataframe, you can achieve this through `unary_union` & `envelope`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from io import StringIO

points = '''geometry
POINT (-20885056.99629 3418931.63321)
POINT (-20825056.99629 3478931.63321)'''
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(points))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry']))

print(gdf)
#                             geometry
# 0  POINT (-20885056.996 3418931.633)
# 1  POINT (-20825056.996 3478931.633)

print(gdf.geometry.unary_union.envelope.wkt)
# POLYGON ((-20885056.99629 3418931.63321, -20825056.99629 3418931.63321, -20825056.99629 3478931.63321, -20885056.99629 3478931.63321, -20885056.99629 3418931.63321))
```

With `(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)` tuples you can use `shapely.geometry.box()`:

```py
from shapely import geometry
bbox_tuple = gdf.total_bounds
print(bbox_tuple)
# [-20885056.99629   3418931.63321 -20825056.99629   3478931.63321]

bbox_polygon = geometry.box(*bbox_tuple)
print(bbox_polygon.wkt)
# POLYGON ((-20825056.99629 3418931.63321, -20825056.99629 3478931.63321, -20885056.99629 3478931.63321, -20885056.99629 3418931.63321, -20825056.99629 3418931.63321))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to first produce point geometries from your coordinates. Simply provide all 4 corners like so:

```
poly = geometry.Polygon(((xmin,ymin), (xmin,ymax), (xmax,ymax), (xmax,ymin)))
```